# Is there a way to export Team Projects and their Work Items from a VSTS (Azure DevOps) instance to an On-premise TFS 2018 Server instance?

Tags: azure, tfs, migration, azure-devops

I need your help to find out if is there a way to export Team Projects and their Work Items from a VSTS (Azure DevOps) instance to an On-premise TFS 2018 Server instance?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no way to just take a team project from VSTS/Azure DevOps and bring it back on-prem.

There are various tools that allow for *synchronization* of some aspects by taking advantage of APIs, but there is always some degree of loss of information involved.

Comment: Hi Daniel. Thank you so much by your answer!

Can you suggest me some of this tools?

Regards.